# surface(2d) fit in MATLAB with anonymous function

Tags: matlab

I want to use `fit` in MATLAB for two dimensions.
I defined function separately and then called it with `fittype`

x has two columns!

```
f=fittype('@(x)myfun(beta1, beta2,beta3, x)')
```

and then customize in options my start point and algorithm.

then use `[results, goodness]=fit(x, zdata,f, options)`, but I have a error

??? Too many inputs to FITTYPE function.

Error in ==> fit at 443
                errstr = handleerr( errid, errmsg, suppresserr );

I also tried with `[results, goodness]=fit([x(:,1), x(:,2)], zdata,f, options)`,

and still have the same problem.

I used `fit -all`

XDATA must be a matrix with one to two columns.

Error in ==> fit at 115
    errstr = handleerr('curvefit:fit:xDataMustBeColumnVector', ...

for me sounds meaningles , since I have my x in two columns!!!!

and then `which fit -all`

/Applications/matlab/MATLAB_R2010a.app/toolbox/curvefit/curvefit/fit.m
/Applications/matlab/MATLAB_R2010a.app/toolbox/stats/@ProbDistUnivParam/fit.m  % ProbDistUnivParam method
/Applications/matlab/MATLAB_R2010a.app/toolbox/stats/@NaiveBayes/fit.m         % NaiveBayes method
/Applications/matlab/MATLAB_R2010a.app/toolbox/stats/@gmdistribution/fit.m     % gmdistribution method

could you please help me to use `fit` and `fittype` to fit my 2 dimension data?
{please don't introduce me meshgrid and other commands.}

Comment: just in a simple way, could you tell me how to define  anonymous function for surf fit with fit type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the parameter `'numindep' = 2` which indicates that your fit is for a surface (i.e has two independent variables).

Here's an example using your function with the Franke data using a string:

```
load franke
ft = fittype('myfun(beta1, beta2, beta3, [x, y])', 'numindep', 2)
[results, goodness] = fit([x, y], z, ft)
```

Here's an example using your function with the Franke data using an anonymous function:

```
load franke
ft = fittype(@(beta1,beta2,beta3, x, y)myfun(beta1, beta2,beta3, [x, y]), 'numindep', 2)
[results, goodness] = fit([x, y], z, ft)
```