# Fitting a smooth curve to dataset containing tuples in MATLAB/OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, rgb, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a dataset of **actual** normalized R,G,B values for a number of pixels in the form of [R, G] values (as B value can be calculated using B = 1 - R - G). All these values are unique. I also have a similar dataset of **observed** R,G,B values in the same format i.e. [R, G]. Since these are observed, these values might not be unique. I want to fit a smooth curve based on Least Squares method on the **observed** values, so that I can get one-to-one correspondence between observed and actual values when reverse mapping **actual** values from **observed** RGB values. Individual fitting of R and G values can be easily done using MATLAB functions but they are not completely independent so the dataset points have to be considered as tuples. Is there any way to do this in MATLAB/OpenCV?

Edit: Simplifying my question a bit, I want a surface fit or a function such that f(R<sub>obs</sub>, G<sub>obs</sub>) -> R<sub>actual</sub> and g(R<sub>obs</sub>, G<sub>obs</sub>) -> G<sub>actual</sub>. So that I can get a net combined mapping h(R<sub>obs</sub>, G<sub>obs</sub>) -> (R<sub>actual</sub>, G<sub>actual</sub>).

Comment: Fitting a curve implies the expectation of some relationship from one point to the next - so are these adjacent pixels along a line? Just trying to form a clearer image in my mind. Also - "dataset points have to be considered as tuples" - do you mean, in effect, that "the optimization has a constraint `R+G+B=1`"?

Comment: @Floris These pixels are from a particular pattern. Take it as a 256*256 pattern. Yes, it has the constraint of R+G+B=1, because of which I can't fit R values and G values separately.

Comment: 256x256 is a surface not a line?? You have two degrees of freedom and calculate B for computing goodness of fit. Is that something you need help with? What is the form of the function you are fitting? Are you using optimization toolbox?

Comment: Ya, it is a surface. So consider 256*256 [R, G] tuples. Let me re-frame my question like this:

Comment: I have a one-to-many mapping of 256*256 tuples(Original) to another set of tuples(Observed). I want to do a reverse mapping of Observed tuples to Original tuples by a smooth function instead of discrete values so that I don't get a many-to-one mapping. Had it been a single variable instead of a tuple, it would have been easily done by using a function of the form f(x) = y (Or vice-versa). I need to do something like f([a, b]) = [x,y]. I haven't used optimization toolbox.

Comment: Do you have a form of the smooth function in mind? Or are you looking for a spline-like fit? Do you have spline toolbox? Any toolboxes?

Comment: I don't have any function/curve in mind. Anything that fits best (might use Least Squares) will do. There's no constraint of toolboxes. The answer to this question explains my problem to a certain extent except the fact that the 2 variables for surface fit might also be dependent in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226321/surface2d-fit-in-matlab-with-anonymous-function

Comment: You do realize that the mapping you are looking for most likely does not exist. Why would you expect there to be a single "best" value for Rfit with which you can predict the most likely Robs - unless you include the (x,y) location as well. Your "function" is likely multi-valued otherwise. A fit F(x,y)-> (R,G,B) is more likely to be successful.

Comment: I don't want to predict Robs. I want to predict Ractual and Gactual from Robs and Gobs. I want to use a 2D surface fit for Robs and Gobs. For selecting the best value, can't we use the least squares method? I know it's confusing but I can clarify further if you have any doubts.

Comment: I don't think that in general you can do what you are asking: "so that I can get one-to-one correspondence between observed and actual values when reverse mapping". A function doesn't necessarily have an inverse. Thus I think it's better to use (XY) coordinates of points to generate the fit. It seems I can't help you.